# responsive div background, but no repeat

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

I'm trying to make this div background to act as a normal 100% image and scale the same way.

My CSS:

```
.videobackground{
margin-top:-5px;
max-width:1140px;
height:348px !important;
background-image:url(imgs/rpp-behind-the-scenes-hero2bg.jpg);
background-position:center; /* IE fix */
-webkit-background-size: contain;
-moz-background-size: contain;
-o-background-size: contain;
background-size: contain;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="videobackground"></div>
```

Here is my issue on desktop it's looking perfectly fine.

Desktop Picture:

[image]

But as soon as I start to scale the page this happens.

Mobile Picture:

[image]

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated, I feel like I've tried just about everything. And the reason I'm using a div background as opposed to just an image, I'm overlaying a youtube embed over the left side of the div.

Thanks so much!

Adam.

Comment: can u send your code or link?? so that i can work on it through firebug

Comment: try this: `background-repeat:no-repeat'

Comment: background-repeat:no-repeat does not work, it only stops it from repeating and shows white space on top and bottom as I scale smaller.

Comment: @Ganesh Give me a few minutes to upload to my server and I'll shoot a link over.

Comment: Have you tried using `background-size:cover` ?

Comment: yes, adding that makes the image larger the rest of the div surrounding it, throwing the image off and not aligning it correctly to the slices.

Comment: oky @adambwhitten will wait for your link

Comment: @GaneshPutta http://adambwhitten.com/rpp-lauren/ <-- the link.

Answer (score 3):

You could add

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

To your css.

So it looks something like

```
.videobackground{
margin-top:-5px;
max-width:1140px;
height:348px !important;
background-image:url(imgs/rpp-behind-the-scenes-hero2bg.jpg);
background-position:center; /* IE fix */
-webkit-background-size: contain;
-moz-background-size: contain;
-o-background-size: contain;
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Also here's a great link on getting full container backgrounds.
https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Also as a side note you could use short hand and combine all your css properties.

```
  background: url(imgs/rpp-behind-the-scenes-hero2bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

Comment: This is what happens with the no repeat, as stated above: http://i.imgur.com/FuSwjuw.png

Comment: Try using background size cover and also add the position fixed property to the background. Like in the link I provided it generally gives much better results

Comment: Just added cover, still looks fine on desktop full width as noted. But this is what happens when you scale: http://i.imgur.com/O8tttoR.png

Comment: Could you provide a link to the page? make sure you also add fixed.

Comment: www.adambwhitten.com/rpp-lauren

Comment: Looks like you're using 3 images instead of one. It'll be very very hard for you to achieve the effect you want by breaking down the image into 3 sections. Ideally you should make a container div the wraps around all the bit-1 elements and give that the background. Also it's generally a bad idea to have a website that is built entirely out of images. You will have a hard time with SEO because the bots wont be able to find any text and also it'll be very hard for you to make content look responsive on different screens.

Comment: Why aren't to concerned with SEO on this page it self, not really a huge issue for us atm. So you would recommend making it one image as the div background and just positioning the embedded video to it's appropriate location?

Comment: Yes. The best thing to do would be to have one big image that is applied to a container element and then add the video in a child element. Hope that helps.

Comment: I guess my question then would be, how do you get the image on the back to scale accordingly, without cutting off the sides of the image, and creating white space on top and bottom of the div when scaled?

Comment: Yes. But you could continue using `contain` instead of `cover` if you don't want the image to scale. Additionally you could try using different image for different screens using media queries. The main problem is that there is no 'one size fits all' when it comes to images on mobile and desktop. You either have to scale the image to fit the parent container or you need to contain its height inside the container (which does not guarantee full cover of parent)

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys! If I find a solution I will post.

Comment: Cheers. Good luck and Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

There are two images in DIVs above and below your `.videobackground` div that contain the same picture, but conflict with your background image.

You should wrap these 3 DIVs with another DIV and assign the background image to *that*  DIV  (and remove it from the others)

(also make sure to use `background-repeat: no-repeat`, `background-size: cover` and `background-position: center center`)

ADDITION AFTER COMMENT:

Your HTML code is (partly):

```
<div class="bit-1">
  <img src="imgs/rpp-behind-the-scenes-hero1.jpg" width="100%">
</div>
<div class="bit-1">
  <div class="videobackground"></div>
</div>
<div class="bit-1">
  <img src="imgs/rpp-behind-the-scenes-hero3.jpg" width="100%">
</div>
```

Change that as I wrote above to something like:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="bit-1">
     <!-- contents here, but no image -->
  </div>
  <div class="bit-1">
    <div class="videobackground"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bit-1">
     <!-- contents here, but no image -->
  </div>
</div>
```

In the CSS, remove the background-image from `.videobackground` and add it to `#wrapper', like

```
#wrapper {
  background: url(imgs/rpp-behind-the-scenes-hero2bg.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Now all three DIVs have one common background image instead of the not-fitting-together three partial images before.

Comment: an example of code would help me visualize what your saying.